# Laravel Not Delete record

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I working on laravel to build my php project . I can retrieve data from database successfully but I can not delete records when press delete button , I trying to delete record using ajax so this my ajax code

```
$('.userdelete').on('click', function () {
    alert('dfsfs');
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'DELETE',
        url: '/users/' + id,
        data: {
            '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
        },
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
            toastr.success('Successfully deleted Post!', 'Success Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
            $('.item' + data['id']).remove();
        },
        error: function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

this is the route

```
Route::resource('users','radcheckController');
```

Users Model

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Users extends Model
{
    protected $table="radcheck";
}
```

this is the controller's destroy function

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $res = Users::where('username', $id)->delete();
}
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: you need to fix, add `_method: 'delete'` to data in ajax

Comment: Can you show us error? are you passing CSRF Token in ajax?

Comment: if you're using $id as a primary key, use User::find($id)->delete()

Comment: this is the error DELETE http://localhost:8000/users/10966417880 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing the id or the username to the end point?
'Cause on your controller you're looking for a username, the parameter is named as id, is that right?

Comment: I passing username

Comment: DELETE http://localhost:8000/users/10966417880 500 (Internal Server Error)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the correct column, but you didn't pick one. Use `find` or `findOrFail` with `$id` or use `first()`.
Right way is:

```
public function destroy($id)

{
    $res = Users::find($id);
    $res->delete();
}
```

or try:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    $res = Users::where('username', $id)->first()->delete();
}
```

Comment: this is the error message DELETE http://localhost:8000/users/10966417880 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Our Controller is right. There is no problem. We just can't connect to the route. Don't use resources. Make your own route with Route::delete.

Comment: I removed the code of destroy and inserted in it echo $id and code return  right value . so we can access the rout